# jquery ajax call in safari MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I have a JavaScript function that makes an ajax call passing in an id.  In safari it doesn't work, in all other browsers it does

```js
function populateContractList(ShowLoader, HideLoader) {
  var frm = document.querySelector("#frmSchedule");
  var id = frm.elements["ID"].value;
  var url = '@Url.Action("Contracts", "Contract")';

  ShowLoader();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    async: true,
    data: { id }
  }).done(function(data) {
    var available = $('#multiselectContract option').length;
    if (available == 0) {
      data.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (!$('#js_multiselect_to_1').find("option:contains('" + obj.ContractId + "')").length) {
          $('#multiselectContract').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", obj.Holder).text(obj.ContractId));
        }
      });
    }

    HideLoader();
  }).fail(function() {
    HideLoader();
    bootbox.alert({
      title: '<div class="text-center text-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;No Contacts Assigned</div>'
    });
  });
}
```

Safari generates this error in the console and the page stops working correctly

> SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '}' instead

the error is on this line

```
data: { id }
```

If I remove both brackets { } it no longer complains, but it does stop working
Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a shorthand object initialiser in `data: { id }`. That is to say, the object will be create with a key matching the variable name, and a value of the variable value.

This is a feature of ES2015 which is [only available in Safari 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) and newer (and not at all in IE). As such, you'll need to use more traditional object initialiser syntax:

```
data: { id: id }
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help, Id actually already just tried that and it worked :-)